# Как элегантно сменить таблицу QTableWidget при итерации цикла?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, for, qtablewidget

Есть несколько таблиц `tableWidget_1`, `tableWidget_2`, `tableWidget_3`, ..и т.д.

Есть такой код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QAction, QTableWidget,QTableWidgetItem,QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

# okk типо приходит с сервера через socket
okk = [(17, 0, 0, 0, 0, '2021-10-16', 0), 
        (16, 22, 22, 33, 44, '2021-10-14', 55), 
        (15, 22, 33, 44, 1, '2021-10-14', 4), 
        (14, 987, 987, 987, 987, '2021-10-14', 987), 
        (13, 11, 22, 33, 44, '2021-10-14', 55), 
        (12, 346, 354, 6346, 2324, '2021-10-11', 34346), 
        (11, 25, 634, 364, 235, '2021-10-11', 634), 
        (10, 534, 63, 436, 754, '2021-10-11', 364), 
        (9, 643, 345, 2356, 34, '2021-10-11', 643), 
        (8, 345, 634, 364, 634, '2021-10-11', 643), 
        (7, 3425, 435, 53, 35, '2021-10-11', 534), 
        (6, 63, 7865, 123, 5632456, '2021-10-11', 230), 
        (5, 11, 22, 33, 44, '2021-10-11', 55), 
        (4, 1, 2, 3, 4, '2021-10-11', 5), 
        (3, 22, 22, 222, 22, '2021-10-10', 222), 
        (2, 777, 777, 777, 777, '2021-10-10', 777), 
        (1, 22, 33, 44, 55, '2021-10-10', 66)]

# маска команд на сервер и обработку таблицы
base = [{'message': 'zavod_1_92_25', 'id': 1}, {'message': 'zavod_2_92_25', 'id': 2}]


class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'ПРИМЕРНЫЙ ПРИМЕР ТАБЛИЦ'
        self.left = 300
        self.top = 300

        self.width = 1000
        self.height = 800
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        

        self.myAddInTableS()


        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget_1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget_2)
        self.setLayout(self.layout) 

        self.show()

    def myAddInTableS(self):
        
        self.tableWidget_1 = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget_1.setRowCount(4)
        self.tableWidget_1.setColumnCount(7)
        self.tableWidget_2 = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget_2.setRowCount(4)
        self.tableWidget_2.setColumnCount(7)

        for item in base:
            message = item['message']
            id_table = item['id']
            print('Отправка команды на серверную часть, для срабатывания запроса и отправки обратно OKK-переменная: ', message)
            print('id_table: ', id_table, ' - Это значение должно сменить номер таблицы, но я не знаю как это сделать. П.О.М.О.Г.И.Т.Е.!')
            self.tableWidget_1.setRowCount(len(okk))

            tablerow = 0

            for row in okk:
                self.tableWidget_1.setItem(tablerow, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[0])))
                self.tableWidget_1.setItem(tablerow, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[1])))
                self.tableWidget_1.setItem(tablerow, 2, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[2])))
                self.tableWidget_1.setItem(tablerow, 3, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[3])))
                self.tableWidget_1.setItem(tablerow, 4, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[4])))
                self.tableWidget_1.setItem(tablerow, 5, QTableWidgetItem(row[5]))
                self.tableWidget_1.setItem(tablerow, 6, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[6])))

                tablerow += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

В моем понимании `ID_TABLE` это должен быть номер таблицы, куда запихивать данные при следующей итерации цикла.

Как сделать замену `tableWidget_1` на `tableWidget_2` при проходе итерации цикла?

Хочу максимально сжатый код.

Ребят прям помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного короче и универсальнее:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, \
    QAction, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, qApp


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, okk, base):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.okk = okk
        self.base = base
        self.tableWidgets = []
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        
        self.myAddInTableS()

    def myAddInTableS(self):
        for i, item in enumerate(self.base):
            message = item['message']
            id_table = item['id']
            print(f'Отправка команды на серверную часть: id={id_table}, message={message}')

            certainTable = QTableWidget(0, 7, objectName=f'tableWidget_{i+1}')
            certainTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Hello', certainTable.objectName(),]) 
            
            for row, data in enumerate(self.okk):
                _data = list(map(str, data ))
                certainTable.insertRow(row)
                for col, item in enumerate(_data):
                    certainTable.setItem(row, col, QTableWidgetItem(item))
                
            self.layout.addWidget(certainTable)
            self.tableWidgets.append(certainTable)
            qApp.processEvents()

        
okk = [
    (17, 0, 0, 0, 0, '2021-10-16', 0), 
    (16, 22, 22, 33, 44, '2021-10-14', 55), 
    (15, 22, 33, 44, 1, '2021-10-14', 4), 
    (14, 987, 987, 987, 987, '2021-10-14', 987), 
    (13, 11, 22, 33, 44, '2021-10-14', 55), 
    (12, 346, 354, 6346, 2324, '2021-10-11', 34346), 
    (11, 25, 634, 364, 235, '2021-10-11', 634), 
    (10, 534, 63, 436, 754, '2021-10-11', 364), 
    (9, 643, 345, 2356, 34, '2021-10-11', 643), 
    (8, 345, 634, 364, 634, '2021-10-11', 643), 
    (7, 3425, 435, 53, 35, '2021-10-11', 534), 
    (6, 63, 7865, 123, 5632456, '2021-10-11', 230), 
    (5, 11, 22, 33, 44, '2021-10-11', 55), 
    (4, 1, 2, 3, 4, '2021-10-11', 5), 
    (3, 22, 22, 222, 22, '2021-10-10', 222), 
    (2, 777, 777, 777, 777, '2021-10-10', 777), 
    (1, 22, 33, 44, 55, '2021-10-10', 66)
]

base = [
    {'message': 'zavod_1_92_25', 'id': 1}, 
    {'message': 'zavod_2_92_25', 'id': 2}
]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow(okk, base)
    ex.setWindowTitle('ПРИМЕРНЫЙ ПРИМЕР ТАБЛИЦ')
    ex.resize(770, 500)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот, за это спасибо)

Comment: @YanWolf пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Вот, что значит не систематическое обучение. Ответ был в начальных уроках по Python

Может кому нужно будет):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QAction, QTableWidget,QTableWidgetItem,QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

okk = [(17, 0, 0, 0, 0, '2021-10-16', 0), 
        (16, 22, 22, 33, 44, '2021-10-14', 55), 
        (15, 22, 33, 44, 1, '2021-10-14', 4), 
        (14, 987, 987, 987, 987, '2021-10-14', 987), 
        (13, 11, 22, 33, 44, '2021-10-14', 55), 
        (12, 346, 354, 6346, 2324, '2021-10-11', 34346), 
        (11, 25, 634, 364, 235, '2021-10-11', 634), 
        (10, 534, 63, 436, 754, '2021-10-11', 364), 
        (9, 643, 345, 2356, 34, '2021-10-11', 643), 
        (8, 345, 634, 364, 634, '2021-10-11', 643), 
        (7, 3425, 435, 53, 35, '2021-10-11', 534), 
        (6, 63, 7865, 123, 5632456, '2021-10-11', 230), 
        (5, 11, 22, 33, 44, '2021-10-11', 55), 
        (4, 1, 2, 3, 4, '2021-10-11', 5), 
        (3, 22, 22, 222, 22, '2021-10-10', 222), 
        (2, 777, 777, 777, 777, '2021-10-10', 777), 
        (1, 22, 33, 44, 55, '2021-10-10', 66)]


base = [{'message': 'zavod_1_92_25', 'id': 1}, {'message': 'zavod_2_92_25', 'id': 2}]


class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'ПРИМЕРНЫЙ ПРИМЕР ТАБЛИЦ'
        self.left = 300
        self.top = 300

        self.width = 1000
        self.height = 800
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        

        self.myAddInTableS()


        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget_1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget_2)
        self.setLayout(self.layout) 

        self.show()


    def myAddInTableS(self):

        self.tableWidget_1 = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget_1.setRowCount(4)
        self.tableWidget_1.setColumnCount(7)
        self.tableWidget_2 = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget_2.setRowCount(4)
        self.tableWidget_2.setColumnCount(7)
        
        for item in base:
            message = item['message']
            id_table = item['id']
            print('Отправка команды на серверную часть, для срабатывания запроса и отправки обратно OKK-переменная: ', message)

#vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

            if id_table == 1:
                certainTable = self.tableWidget_1
            elif id_table == 2:
                certainTable = self.tableWidget_2

#^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

            certainTable.setRowCount(len(okk)) #<---------------------------

            tablerow = 0

            for row in okk:
                certainTable.setItem(tablerow, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[0]))) #<----
                certainTable.setItem(tablerow, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[1]))) #<----
                certainTable.setItem(tablerow, 2, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[2]))) #<----
                certainTable.setItem(tablerow, 3, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[3]))) #<----
                certainTable.setItem(tablerow, 4, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[4]))) #<----
                certainTable.setItem(tablerow, 5, QTableWidgetItem(row[5])) #<----
                certainTable.setItem(tablerow, 6, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[6]))) #<----

                tablerow += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```